# Is the following argument "Let $H$ be Lie group and an open subgroup of $G$ a Lie group, then $H$ is closed" true?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In my notes of Lie algebra I have the following statement, which is unproven and has no further clarification:

> Let $H$ be Lie group and an open subgroup of $G$ a Lie group, then $H$ is closed

Is this true or is it a mistake? and if it is, how is it proven?

Comment: Write $G$ as the union of the cosets of $H$. What can you say about the complement of $H$?

Comment: True for topological groups in general, no need for "Lie".  You did learn about topological groups before you began Lie groups, right?

Comment: No, I didn't see anything about topological groups

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226847/open-subgroups-of-a-topological-group-are-closed